# Ubuntu 22.04 asks for manual fcsk

Tags: fsck

I started my laptop today and get this:

[image]

What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Update: fsck helped! But it came with these messages. Do I need to worry?
[image]

Comment: Looks like your file system is seriously messed up. Maybe a hard drive error. 'The drive being encrypted makes a recovery even harder.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Then I will prepare for worst case and also do a disk check.

Comment: If you have access to (an install of) `smartmontools`, you can use `smartctl --all ...` to check if the drive is still ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the laptop was closed without shutting down properly. This may happen if it runs out of battery in sleep mode.

Run the command

```
fsck -y /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root
```

Afterwards, type `exit` tor reboot.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! It just booted up again.
Do I need to worry about the second screen in my question?

Comment: No problem. Type exit to reboot. If that works, don't worry. But still do a disk check, just in case there is any error.

Comment: "smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1p1" came out with: 
"Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
No Errors Logged".

Comment: That's great! Nothing to worry about